# How can i set credential charset with httpclient 4.3

Tags: character-encoding, apache-httpclient-4.x, credentials

`AuthPNames.CREDENTIAL_CHARSET` is deprecated!?

I don't know how to interpret:

> (4.3) use RequestConfig and constructor parameters of
>   AuthSchemeProviders.

From the [documentation](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/auth/params/AuthPNames.html).

Can anyone give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Registry<AuthSchemeProvider> authSchemeRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<AuthSchemeProvider>create()
        .register(AuthSchemes.BASIC, new BasicSchemeFactory(Consts.UTF_8))
        .register(AuthSchemes.DIGEST, new DigestSchemeFactory(Consts.UTF_8))
        .register(AuthSchemes.NTLM, new NTLMSchemeFactory())
        .register(AuthSchemes.SPNEGO, new SPNegoSchemeFactory())
        .register(AuthSchemes.KERBEROS, new KerberosSchemeFactory())
        .build();

CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
        .setDefaultAuthSchemeRegistry(authSchemeRegistry)
        .build();
```